# JavaScript Alarm Clock Won't Play Sound

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to build a clock with simple HTML and JavaScript, but I've come to a halt. I've got the clock, and can choose my time for the alarm, but the sound never goes off.

```
function alarmOn() {
  if (alarmTime = startTime()) {
    var audio = new Audio('school-bell.mp3');
    audio.play();
```

https://webpage-jbedford23.c9users.io/NewClock.html

If you need access to full code. Lt me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that `school-bell.mp3` is in the same folder as the page you are running the code on?

Comment: `if (alarmTime = startTime())`? Is that how you do comparison?

Comment: yes it is in the same folder and i tried "==" as well it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```js
var today= new Date();
var alarmTime = "nothing";
var toCompare = "nothing";
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    toCompare = h + ":" + m;
    if (String(alarmTime) === String(toCompare)) {
      //new Audio('./school-bell.mp3').play()
      var audio = new Audio('school-bell.mp3');
      audio.play();
      console.log("Comparison passed");

    }
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

// curTime = (checkTime(today.getHours()) + ":" + checkTime(today.getMinutes()));
// var fresh = setTimeout(curTime, 1000);

function alarmSet() {
  hourNum = document.getElementById("hour");
  hValue = hourNum.options[hourNum.selectedIndex].value;
  minNum = document.getElementById("mins");
  mValue = minNum.options[minNum.selectedIndex].value;
  alarmTime = hValue + ":" + mValue;
  
}
function alarmOn() {
 console.log("alarmTime = " + alarmTime + " | " + "toCompare = " + toCompare);
  if (String(alarmTime) === String(toCompare)) {
    //new Audio('./school-bell.mp3').play()
    var audio = new Audio('school-bell.mp3');
    audio.play();
    console.log("Comparison passed");
    
  }
}
function alarmOff() {
  document.all.sound.src = "";
  alarmTime="";
}
```

```css
#txt {
    height: 100px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    padding-top: 70px;
    font-family: courier, monospace;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()" style="background-color: black" >

<div id="txt"style="color:#00ff00" align=center ></div>
 <table width=50% border=1 style="color:white">
<tr>
<td align=middle style="color:white">
<input type=radio name=alarmOnOff onClick="alarmOn()">On
<input type=radio name=alarmOnOff onClick="alarmOff()" checked>Off
<td align=middle>
Set Alarm:
<br>
<select id=hour name=hourOpt onChange="alarmSet()" size=1> //Opti
<option value="00">00<option value="01">01<option value="02">02<option value="03">03
<option value="04">04<option value="05">05<option value="06">06<option value="07">07
<option value="08">08<option value="09">09<option value="10">10<option value="11">11
<option selected value="12">12
<option value="13">13<option value="14">14<option value="15">15<option value="16">16
<option value="17">17<option value="18">18<option value="19">19<option value="20">20
<option value="21">21<option value="22">22<option value="23">23
</option>
</select>
<select id=mins name=minOpt onChange="alarmSet()" size=1>
<option selected value="00">00<option value="01">01<option value="02">02<option value="03">03
<option value="04">04<option value="05">05<option value="06">06<option value="07">07
<option value="08">08<option value="09">09<option value="10">10<option value="11">11
<option value="12">12<option value="13">13<option value="14">14<option value="15">15
<option value="16">16<option value="17">17<option value="18">18<option value="19">19
<option value="20">20<option value="21">21<option value="22">22<option value="23">23
<option value="24">24<option value="25">25<option value="26">26<option value="27">27
<option value="28">28<option value="29">29<option value="30">30<option value="31">31
<option value="32">32<option value="33">33<option value="34">34<option value="35">35
<option value="36">36<option value="37">37<option value="38">38<option value="39">39
<option value="40">40<option value="41">41<option value="42">42<option value="43">43
<option value="44">44<option value="45">45<option value="46">46<option value="47">47
<option value="48">48<option value="49">49<option value="50">50<option value="51">51
<option value="52">52<option value="53">53<option value="54">54<option value="55">55
<option value="56">56<option value="57">57<option value="58">58<option value="59">59
</option>
</select>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="txt"style="color:#00ff00" align=center ></div>

</body>
```

I think the mistake might be related to the way you are comparing alarmTime and statTime. In Javascript, comparison operators are like so:

```
===
==
!==
!=
```

So if your time is same format, then change:

```
if (alarmTime = startTime()) {
```

To:

```
if (alarmTime === startTime()) {
```

or:

```
if (alarmTime == startTime()) {
```

For more info on comparison operators, please go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?v=control

Hope this helps,

EDIT:

```
if (alarmTime = startTime())
```

The comparison operator is wrong as I mentioned above, on top of that, you are comparing a variable with a function that returns nothing:

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}
```

You can create a variable that stores current time in string format, because your `alarmTime` is created that way:

```
alarmTime = hValue + ":" + mValue;
```

That way you can make a comparison that makes sense.

Comment: ok i changed my comparison all together it now looks like this....

var today = new Date()

var h = today.getHours();

var m = today.getMinutes(); 

var s = today.getSeconds();
if (alarmTime == [h + ":" + m + ":" + s])

i even put in a console log to see if they were generating the same outcome and they are but the sounds still wont play......

Comment: @Jordan check my edit, should give you an idea of where you're going wrong, there was lots of things wrong with your code. Go full screen, and check the result in console.

Answer (score -1):

this is what i would do on android studio.

try MediaPlayer, it has many options.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, ringtone);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```